# D3 time parse - Parsing only year-month

Tags: d3.js

Using D3 version 3.5.17, I have noticed a strange behaviour of the time parser.

[JSfiddle for the below example.](https://jsfiddle.net/raino01r/q1pt0zdr/)

For example using:

```
var data = [
    {'month': '2015-01', 'cnt':1},
    {'month': '2015-02', 'cnt':2},
    {'month': '2015-03', 'cnt':3},
    {'month': '2015-04', 'cnt':4},
    {'month': '2015-05', 'cnt':5},
    {'month': '2015-06', 'cnt':6},
    {'month': '2015-06', 'cnt':7}
],
    dateFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m');
data.forEach(function(x) {
    x.month = dateFormat.parse(x.month);
    console.log(x.month, x.cnt);
});
```

I have the following:

```
Date 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z 1
Date 2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z 2
Date 2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z 3
Date 2015-03-31T23:00:00.000Z 4  <-- ?
Date 2015-04-30T23:00:00.000Z 5  <-- ?
Date 2015-05-31T23:00:00.000Z 6  <-- ?
Date 2015-05-31T23:00:00.000Z 7  <-- ?
```

Is this a normal behaviour? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Is there any way that I should edit the data before parsing so to have a correct month?

Comment: Where do you live? Southern hemisphere? Your country probably has a daylight savings that ends in March.

Comment: is there a way to suppress the daylight time change when parsing only dates?

Comment: Ops, my bad: you have one hour **less** in March, meaning that your country's daylight savings **starts** on March. So, you live in the Northern Hemisphere.

Comment: You could set the hour to the noon, that would avoid changing the day. BTW, this behaviour is normal. I'll quote Bostock, D3 creator, about time scales, the general idea applies to your problem: *"A d3.time.scale should be used when you want to display time as a continuous variable, such as when you want to take into account the fact that days can range from 23-25 hours due to **daylight savings changes**, and years can vary from 365-366 days due to leap years."* (emphasis mine)